# JS Files Keep Crashing in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, crash

I have VS 2010, Windows 7.

Every time I try to make changes in my js files in one of my projects Vs keeps "not responding" and I have no clue why.

Anyone ideas how I can debug this? It seems to only be with js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try all standard things:

- Disable all plugins and see if it happens
- make sure to install all updates
- if all fails - you can debug VS with another instance of VS and see if it gives you any clues.

Comment: How can I debug it with another VS instance?

Comment: @chobo2, Devenv is just a process - so start another VS, Debug->Attach to process pick managed or native mode and attach. Than Debug->Break all and look at Debug->Windows->Threads. There is some small chance that you'll find some suspicious plugin on the stack that would give you clue what may be going wrong... But don't hope for much. Also watching Output window of second instance of VS for exceptions may be useful...